# Download smartcontract's bytecode

Tags: foundry, cast, anvil

Is there a way to download a smartcontract's bytecode with foundry and inject this bytecode into a local Anvil blockchain (at a given address) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do a fork of Mainnet to your local. Then just locally deploy your contract and do your thing

```
anvil --fork-url https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/$INFURA_KEY
```

For more information, see here: https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/forking-mainnet-with-cast-anvil

[image]

1. Here I have a polygon fork running in my terminal: anvil --fork-url https://polygon.meowrpc.com
2. In another window, I executed mint and balanceOf sequentially. I got the result from balanceOf == 2 locally
3. The browser window shows that the balanceOf contract in poligon network returns 1

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how I can choose which contract I want to fork with this command

Comment: You can execute any known contract in mainnet locally on your computer in anvil with a change in local storage. Without changing the storage in mainnet

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there is no way to "copy and paste" a smartcontract ? Thanks

Comment: maybe create2 ?

Comment: Thanks but create2 must be run on a smartcontract ? I would like to do this from my computer...